# Is there a way to download react websites?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, source-maps

I know it's possible to download the source code of a website along with all resources (css, html, JavaScript...) using chrome, httrack, wget, etc...

A react website can be downloaded the same way, I was wondering if its possible to convert the react webpack source maps to jsx. The way react developer tools is able to show you what the source code looks like along with the component states and contexts.

Comment: Yes perhaps download using Save As?

Comment: In theory? Sure. In practice, the code you see is extremely unlikely to be the true source code, but rather transpiled code.

Comment: @Slbox It really doesn't matter.

Comment: The point is downloading a react app as a react app. The event handlers would still be attached since they are in the source code.

Comment: @jspcal save as downloads the sourcemaps as plain javascript files, I want them to be converted to JSX or `React.createElement(...)` in the least.